# Ubunto Core New Sudoer(Snappy)

Tags: permissions, ssh, sudo, ubuntu-core

Is there any documentation or tutorial on how to create a new user with admin privileges in Ubuntu Core?

So far, I can only log in to my Raspberry 4 with Ubuntu Core using only my ubuntu.com account and public key.
What I want is to create a new user that has admin privileges when I ssh to it!

I created a new user and tried to give it `sudo` access with `sudo adduser --extrausers ubuntu` and `sudo usermod -aG sudo ubuntu`. When I log in with ubuntu username and trying to `sudo`, i get this error `[sudo] password for ubuntu:  ubuntu is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Can anyone please clarify how to create another sudo capable user in UBUNTU CORE?

Thanks

Comment: Did `usermod` work without error? Is the new 'ubuntu' user really in the `sudo` group? (Check  `/var/lib/extrausers`, since /etc/passwd is read-only in Core). Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/873400/19626

Comment: You are right, usermod didn't finish without error! It produced the following `usermod: /etc/group.2531: Read-only file system
usermod: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.`

ubuntu user is listed in `/var/lib/extrausers/group` and `/passwd`. There is no `sudo` file in `/var/lib/extrausers`

Comment: Looks like you must manually edit /var/lib/extragroups. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-add-extra-user-to-group/13321 for an example of Ubuntu developers discussing the same problem.

Comment: I believe this is no help to me then. I would like just a secondary account to work with, in case i can't access it with my ubuntu.com account! Why did they make it so hard?

Comment: They didn't intend to make it *hard*. They made it *secure*. Core was originally intended for embedded devices: Highly automated, network-connected, very limited user interaction, long periods of time being ignored by humans entirely. That makes it a wonderful target for bad guys. Many Pi-type devices tend to have more robust user interaction than originally envisioned -- humans are really good at doing the unexpected and hitting the boundaries. My own experimental Pi-type devices run Ubuntu Server or Raspbian instead of Core precisely because the  security is so strict.

Comment: However, I do have a *finished* automation project that does indeed use Core as intended: Always-on, very rare human logins, self-updating securely and reliably, talking to other machines pursuing it's simple, reliable tasks.

Comment: Yeah i understand that. That's why i am just reinstalling ubuntu server on my Pi. Thanks for the help and clarifications!